# Passing function pointer with scope resolution operator arduino

Tags: c++, c, header, arduino

I'm a newbie to arduino and programming. 
I've included a library inside my own library in arduino, but first library contains a function which has a pointer function as a parameter. It is an interrupt service routine(ISR) but I need to call a function in my cpp file when interrupt is occurred. So I need to pass the pointer of that function to the first library code. It works well when I use it in .ino file, I can pass it like,

```
attachInterrupt(functionISR_name);
```

but when I use it in .cpp file, I get errors. my function is like,

```
void velocity::functionISR_name(){
//some code
}
```

but how can I pass the pointer of this function to the first library function?  I tried this way but got errors,

```
attachInterrupt(velocity::functionISR_name);
```

Comment: "I get errors". What are the errors?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot pass a method to a function which expects a function, unless you define it static.

write it static :

```
static void velocity::functionISR_name()
```

and

```
attachInterrupt(&velocity::functionISR_name);
```

Unfortunately the static method is not bound to a specific instance any more. You should use it only together with a singleton. On Arduino you should write the class like shown below in the code snipped:

```
class velocity
{
    static velocity *pThisSingelton;
 public:
    velocity()
    {
      pThisSingelton=this;
    }

    static void functionISR_name()
    {
      pThisSingelton->CallWhatEverMethodYouNeeded();
      // Do whatever needed.
    }

   // … Your methods
};

velocity *velocity::pThisSingelton;
velocity YourOneAndOnlyInstanceOfThisClass;

void setup()
{
  attachInterrupt(&velocity::functionISR_name);

  // …other stuff…
}
```

This looks ugly, but in my opinion it is totally okay with Arduino as the opportunities are very limited on such a system.

Thinking again over it, I would personal go for the approach Sorin mentioned in his answer above. That would be more like that:

```
class velocity
{
 public:
    velocity()
    {
    }

    static void functionISR_name()
    {
      // Do whatever needed.
    }

   // … Your methods
};

velocity YourOneAndOnlyInstanceOfThisClass;

void functionISR_name_delegation()
{
  YourOneAndOnlyInstanceOfThisClass.functionISR_name();
}

void setup()
{
  attachInterrupt(functionISR_name_delegation);

  // …other stuff…
}
```

It would also save you some bytes for the pointer you need in the first example.

As a site note: For the future, please post the exact code (for e.g. attachInterrupt needs more parameter) and copy&paste the error messages. Usually error are exact at a place you do not suspect. This question was an exception. Normally I and other would ask for better specification.

Answer (score 1):

You pass a pointer to the function but the function is a class member. Likely the call will be invalid because the `this` pointer will be garbage(may compile fine but will throw strange errors at runtime).

You need to define a plain vanilla function, outside of any class, and use that.
If you don't have a very complex project you can get away with having a global pointer to the class instance you should use and just delegate the call in your new function.
If you want to do thing the right way you need some mechanism to get the instance pointer I talked about above. Usually this involves either a singleton or some factory pattern.

Example:

```
class Foo {
  void method() {
    x = 5;
  }
  int x;
}
```

Having a callback on method will crash because you have an invalid pointer for `this` so `x=5` will write 5 somewhere randomly in memory.
What you need is somehting like:

```
static Foo* foo_instance;  // Initialized somewhere else.
void method_delegator() {
  foo_instance->method();
}
```

Now you can pass `method_delegator` to the function. It will work because you now also pass `foo_instance` for `this` pointer.